# MongoDB findby a column and count by other

Tags: mongodb

I got a `MongoDB` collection with the following object structure,

```
{
    name: "hotel",
    products: [
       {
          id: 1,
          name: "flower"
       },
       {
          id: 350,
          name: "chocolate"
       }
    ]
}
```

Need to find all the objects that:

a) have the name "hotel" and

b) the products number is bigger than 4. `count($products)`

I tried without success the following:

```
db.foo.find($and: [{name: "hotel"}, {products: {$gt: 4}}]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the number of elements in the products array, use a combination of the **[dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)** and [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) to look for the array index 4 (because array indexes in JavaScript are 0-based). If that index exists then it means your document has an array with size greater or equal to 5. Your final query should look like

```
var query = { "name": "hotel", "products.4": { "$exists": true } };
db.foo.find(query);
```

Another option is to use the [**`$where`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#where) operator:

```
var query = { "name": "hotel", "products" : { "$exists": true }, "$where": "this.products.length > 4"} )
db.foo.find(query);
```

Both queries tested with this sample data:

```
db.foo.insert([
{
    name: "hotel",
    products: [
       {
          id: 1,
          name: "flower"
       },
       {
          id: 350,
          name: "chocolate"
       }
    ]
},
{
    name: "hotel",
    products: [
       {
          id: 1,
          name: "flower"
       },
       {
          id: 350,
          name: "chocolate"
       },
       {
          id: 380,
          name: "candy"
       },
       {
          id: 390,
          name: "milk"
       },
       {
          id: 3,
          name: "newspaper"
       },
    ]
}
])
```

The queries above return the document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("551d6706180e849972938f8e"),
    "name" : "hotel",
    "products" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 1,
            "name" : "flower"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 350,
            "name" : "chocolate"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 380,
            "name" : "candy"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 390,
            "name" : "milk"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 3,
            "name" : "newspaper"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes in documentation a found the `$size` operator but the problem is that after it do not take an other operator like `$gt`

Comment: Changed the query to use the dot operator to check for the existence of the array length

Comment: Tried the other option as well?

Comment: Also returning nothing

Comment: Can you update your question with two sample documents that we can test with from our ends? Because I have tested the queries with my sample documents and they work.